# Ubuntu Installation "Permission Denied"

Tags: permissions, software-installation, wubi

First of all, I tried to download the .iso file and burnt it on a DVD, but the setup didn't show up. Then, I tried with the desktop one and when the setup was about to end, an error window popped up saying "Permission Denied". I searched through the internet, and tried open only wubi.exe with the .iso file in the same folder, I disabled the firewall, I clicked on the wubi.exe and the .iso file propieties and clicked "unlock block" but It was all the same. I tried like five times at least and it still doesn't do nothing. My current operating system is windows 7 ultimate service pack 1.

This is my log http://pastebin.com/NUtVQbi6

I really do need help :c

Comment: Wubi is kind of dead... do a dual boot.. partition like this:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kvzW23Nb5Ls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wubi does not work. Boot into your DVD and install that way. If you have no spare space on HDD,you may resize current partition with GParted or from `Windows - System Settings - Administration`

Answer (score 0):

See the Forums Staff recommendations on WUBI:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2229766
As was mentioned, it's not supported any longer.